# Creating PDF From String Creates Blank Screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, pdf, quartz-2d

I'm trying to create a PDF file, with the content of the PDF being text stored in an NSMutableString, and the string is stored on the disk. For some reason though, the PDF is coming out blank. I've been going over this code for a while now and can't figure out why the PDF is not being created with the contents of the string. I NSLogged the string, and the text is definitely in there. Here is the code I'm using, the string in which the data is stored is `stringToSave`:

```
- (void)createPDFfromString:(NSMutableString*)string saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
     CGRect stringRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, stringRect, myDictionary);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    UIFont *theFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

    [stringToSave drawInRect:stringRect withFont:theFont]; 

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

}
```

If anyone could detect where I'm going wrong and let me know how to fix it, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I didn't put in the code that I'm using to save, because that part is working A-okay.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't save anything. And the code you posted makes use of non-existent variables `myDictionary` and `stringToSave`. The posted code ignore both parameters of this method.

Comment: @rmaddy Well Apparently I have no idea what I'm doing then, could you show me how to make this happen?

Comment: Start by posting your actual (relevant) code. When ever you have a question about code, you must post the actual real code, not "similar" code.